# implementing canActivate auth guard in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, canactivate

I have a service with this function that returns true or false on rather or not a token is valid

```
loggedIn() {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/validateToken')
  .map(res => res.json()).map(data => data.success);
}
```

I have a auth guard with can activate on protected routes that uses this.

```
  canActivate(){
    this.authService.loggedIn().subscribe(res => {
      if(res) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
```

But i get this error.

> incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.   Types of property
>   'canActivate' are incompatible.
>       Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean |
>   Promise | Obser...'.
>         Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Promise | Observable'.

How can i implement what I'm trying to do here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `canActivate` function must return a boolean, a promise of a boolean, or an observable of a boolean.

In your case, you return nothing. Probably because you ommited the `return` in your function.

But it wouldn't work if you add it, because then, you would return a subscription, which isn't accepted by the signature.

What you could do is this :

```
canActivate() {
  return this.authService.loggedIn().map(res => {
    if(!res) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }
    return res;
  });
}
```

With this code, you comply with the signature, and keep your routing logic.

Comment: What's the need to use `.map` function again when it was already gets used in the service layer, so dont you think in canActivate you need to use `subscribe` ?

Comment: Also just curious to know, if we replace `.subscribe` with `.map` then your answer is similer to mine isn't it ?

Comment: Using `map` again allows one to implement custom logic inside the guard. The first `map` is used in the auth service, meaning it can't interact with the guard. And `map` returns an Observable, meanwhile `subscribe` returns a Subscription. So no, the answers aren't similar, because mine is following the signature, and yours isn't.